# pass php array to jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I got a page with a form to fill it with custormers info. I got previous custormers data stored in a php array. With a dropdownlist  users can fill the form with my stored data.

what i have is a jquery function that triggers when the  value changes and inside that function i whould like to update the form values with my stored data (in my php array).

Problem is that i dont know how to pass my php array to the jquery function, any idea ??

this is how i fill the array:

```
$contador_acompanantes = 0;

foreach ($acompanantes->Persona as $acomp) 
{
  $numero = $acomp->Numero;
  $apellidos = $acomp->Apellidos;
  $nombre = $acomp->Nombre;

  $ACOMPANANTES[$contador_acompanantes] = $ficha_acomp;
  $contador_acompanantes++; 
}
```

got my select object:

```
<select name="acompanante_anterior" id="acompanante_anterior">
<option value="1" selected>Acompañante</option>
<option value="2">acompanante1</option>
<option value="2">acompanante2</option>
</select>
```

and this is my code for the jquery function (it is in the same .php page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
$('#acompanante_anterior').on('change', function() 
    {

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
$.each(arrayFromPHP, function (i, elem) {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Comment: i am testig this code with a simple array and trying to get an Alert('') for each value in my string and i am not getting anyting

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely want to use `json_encode`, embed the JSON in the page, and parse it with [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Using this method, you should be aware of escaping `</script>`, quotes, and other entities. Also, standard security concerns apply. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/fjEgj/

HTML:

```
<select><option>---</option><option>Hello</option><option>World</option></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var encoded_json_from_php = '{"Hello":[1,2,3], "World":[4,5,6]}';
    var json = JSON.parse(encoded_json_from_php);
</script>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        $(this).unbind("change");
        var val = json[$(this).val()];
        var select = $(this);
        $(this).empty();
        $.each(val, function(i, v) {
            select.append("<option>" + v + "</option>");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
    $('#acompanante_anterior').on('change', function() 
        {
            my_array = new Array();

            <?php foreach($array as $key->val)?>
                my_array['<?php echo $key?>'] = '<?php echo $val;?>';
            <?php endif; ?>

        });
    });
    </script>
```