# How do you assign a PHP array to jQuery array?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I am unable to figure out how to assign `PHP` array to `jQuery` array?.

I want to do something like the following:

```
var jQueryArray = <?php $phpArray; ?>;
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Duplicate/Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758471/pass-php-array-to-jquery-function

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [json encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

> json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value

**Example:**

```
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
```

Comment: @McGafter Good catch!

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
var jQueryArray = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
```

Comment: Err... Isn't something missing?

Comment: Yes, the `echo` was missing. Sorry, I have updated the code

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function:

```
var jQueryArray = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use json_encode

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that PHP json_encode will only work on UTF8 encoded text ...

```
$jsonString = json_encode(array_map(utf8_encode, $rawArray));
```

would be a more universal solution I think, but I'm a bit tired so 'scuse any coding gaffs ...

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to be a JQuery array, it's a javascript array (just to clarify since it's sounds like you're probably a noob). Set your JS array to this:

```
<?php echo json_encode($phpArray);?>
```

See php json_encode docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @mplungjan haha i know - i shouldnt have wasted time getting the link

Answer (score -1):

You can use Json or use foreach in HTML file

```
<?php foreach($phpArray as $key => $val): ?>
      jQueryArray[<?php echo $key; ?>] = <?php echo $val; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You need some quotes there