# Use PHP Array As Data Source For DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to jQuery and am attempting to use jQuery array as the datasource for the jQuery DataTable.  The array is set-up exactly as I need, and I have verified such from using echo json_encode($data);

And this is the jQuery code I'm using....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
alert(information.toString());
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-table').dataTable({
            data: information,
            columns: [
                { title: 'Salesman' },
                { title: 'Office' },
                { title: 'Title' },
                { title: 'Salary' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `alert()` on arrays of objects. Use `console.log()` and inspect results in browser dev tools console. The column definitions also need a `data` property to match the properties in your objects. Doesn't appear to be anything wrong passing the data from php to javascript as per what you see in the alert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass php array to jquery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758471/pass-php-array-to-jquery-function)

Comment: @charlietfl - is it just console.log(information)

Comment: Yes...then open your console (F12)

Comment: @charlietfl - that gives me an error of ```Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=my-table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0.
```

Comment: Need to see what objects look like in array...just a sample

Comment: @charlietfl - how can I show you the jQuery array?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(information[0]))`

Comment: That gives me what I expect ```[{"Salesman":"Harris Teeter","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"}]
```

Comment: OK so in columns `{ title: 'Salesman' , data:'Salesman'}` etc should work. The `data` is for row cells

Comment: If I'm following you're saying I need to strip out the values from the array?

Comment: No...you need to tell the plugin which object property belongs in which column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example you have an array of variable in PHP :

```
<?php
$information = array(
    array("Salesman1" => "Harris 1","Title"=>"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office"=>"Home","Salary"=>"500000.00"),
    array("Salesman2" => "Harris 2","Title"=>"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office"=>"Home","Salary"=>"500000.00"),
    array("Salesman3" => "Harris 3","Title"=>"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office"=>"Home","Salary"=>"500000.00"),
    array("Salesman4" => "Harris 4","Title"=>"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office"=>"Home","Salary"=>"500000.00"),
    array("Salesman5" => "Harris 5","Title"=>"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office"=>"Home","Salary"=>"500000.00")
);
?>
```

And we want to output it as JSON format using json_encode function:

```
<?php
 echo json_encode($information);
?>
```

Will producing this:

> [{"Salesman":"Harris 1","Title":"Consulting JavaScript
>   Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris
>   2","Title":"Consulting JavaScript
>   Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris
>   3","Title":"Consulting JavaScript
>   Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris
>   4","Title":"Consulting JavaScript
>   Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris
>   5","Title":"Consulting JavaScript
>   Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris
>   6","Title":"Consulting JavaScript
>   Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"}]

Now as you embed this result inside javascript variable:

```
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
```

In client browser it will generated like this:

```
var information = [{"Salesman":"Harris 1","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris 2","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris 3","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris 4","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris 5","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},{"Salesman":"Harris 6","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"}]
```

Above result is your javascript datasource. We use it with Datatables [Data option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data). Some example in [Datatables Javascript Sourced Data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html). It can be  this can be arrays or objects.

When your PHP array got specific key index name, it will converted to same key in JSON object. So in Datatables this object key need to included inside [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option. You can use Datatables [colums.title](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) to set column name too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-table').dataTable({
        data: information,
        columns: [
            { data: 'Salesman', title: 'Salesman' },
            { data: 'Office', title: 'Office' },
            { data: 'Title', title: 'Title' },
            { data: 'Salary', title: 'Salary' }
        ]
    });
});
```

**See and run the demo snippet below:**

```js
var information = [
{"Salesman":"Harris Teeter","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},
{"Salesman":"Adam Smith","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},
{"Salesman":"Mirole","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},
{"Salesman":"Jave Mocha","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},
{"Salesman":"Airis","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},
{"Salesman":"Steve Mat","Title":"Consulting JavaScript Architect","Office":"Home","Salary":"500000.00"},
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-table').dataTable({
        data: information,
        columns: [
            { data: 'Salesman', title: 'Salesman' },
            { data: 'Office', title: 'Office' },
            { data: 'Title', title: 'Title' },
            { data: 'Salary', title: 'Salary' }
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="my-table" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Salesman</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Salesman</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var information = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>');
console.log(information);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-table').dataTable({
            data: information,
            columns: [
                { title: 'Salesman' },
                { title: 'Office' },
                { title: 'Title' },
                { title: 'Salary' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

With `console.log`, you will see if your array is correctly parsed, and also using `JSON.parse` to pass your array from `PHP` to `JS` is a better practice in my experience, less risky for syntax errors.

Comment: Why would you ever need to do that? OP's alert is clearly showing an array of objects anyway

Comment: @charlietfl you are right, alert shows that syntax error was not the problem here...