# Setting the DataSource Of jQuery DataTables As An Array

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am attempting to set the source of my DataTable as an array, but I am getting this error:

`Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=my-table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0`

This is my syntax that I am wanting to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
alert(information.toString());
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-table').dataTable({
            data: information,
            columns: [
                { title: 'Employee' },
                { title: 'TotalSales' },
                { title: '30DaySales' },
                { title: '60DaySales' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

What alterations need to be made to the code so that the error is removed and the DataTable is displayed?

**EDIT**
And below is the output of console.log so you can see the format my array is in.

```
Console.log(JSON.stringify(information[0]))
[{"Employee":"Mitch McConell","Total Sales:"1,000.00","30DaySales:"750.00","60DaySales":"350.00"}]
```

Comment: It is same from what you asking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260055/use-php-array-as-data-source-for-datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know Data Table well, but it looks like you're mixing up the [title](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) and [data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) properties.

I think you need to include the `data` property on your columns.

```
            columns: [
                { data: 'Employee' },
                { data: 'TotalSales' },
                { data: '30DaySales' },
                { data: '60DaySales' }
            ]
```